# Add price label in chartkick.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm using chartkick to generate a bar chart, with this data that generated via ajax in ruby on rails,

```
 @data = [
             {
               name: "Fruits", 
               data: [["2010", 10], ["2020", 16], ["2030", 28]]
             },
             {
               name: "Meats", 
               data: [["2010", 24], ["2020", 22], ["2030", 19]]
             },
             {
               name: "Vegetables", 
               data: [["2010", 20], ["2020", 23], ["2030", 29]]
             }
           ]
```

All I want to ask is how to add like $ label, so in example, the bar label would show 20$ in 2010 for vegetables?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the `suffix` option for this:

```
<%= line_chart data, suffix: "$" %>
```